# Why does my application freeze when displaying a JOptionPane on top of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I have written an application inside a JFrame window, and would like to have an error message pop up if that is needed. However, when I call "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()", the application freezes and the only way to stop it is by using task manager.
Here is a trimmed down version of my code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameMain {
    public JFrame jframe;
    public Canvas canvas;

    private AtomicReference<Dimension> canvasSize = new AtomicReference<Dimension>();

    public void initialize(int width, int height) {
    try {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("testapp");
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.jframe = frame;
        ComponentAdapter adapter = new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                resize();
            }
        };

        canvas.addComponentListener(adapter);
        canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Dimension dim = this.canvas.getSize();
        } catch (LWJGLException le) {
            le.printStackTrace();
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "oops!");
    }
    public void resize()
    {
        Dimension dim = this.canvas.getSize();
        canvasSize.set(dim);
        dim = null;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it might be doing that?

Comment: Do you use concurrency in your app? Can you test your code with leaving just `new JFrame(...), setVisible, showMessageDialog` and see if it works then?

Comment: @pajton: that works. Hm.. let's see what happens if I enable everything one by one

Comment: Well, that's just the technique of debugging problem: now you can start adding your code back piece by piece and see which piece of code causes problem.

Comment: @pajton: the problem turned out to be an openGL context sitting in the JFrame. I have tried for quite a while, but there was no way of getting the error message to appear at the same time as the frame while keeping things responsive. I'll probably have to find a workaround of some kind, but thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Great that you found what causes problem! Still, if you need help you can post another, more detailed question:).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
private void ShowMessage(String message) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: A Life saver for us. Our application totally freezes without this, I'm not sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the frame instead of null there

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "oops!");
```

And don't mix awt and swing (JFrame and Canvas) together

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have passed true to setAlwaysOnTop of the JFrame.Try passing  false.
`setAlwaysOnTop(false);`